# Getting Streaming Data to Right Client(s)

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, akka, spray

I have streaming data coming in to a platform that looks like this:

RestAPI -> AWS Kinesis Stream A -> Custom Analytics Engine

Once each datum is processed by the Analytics engine, the result needs to be pushed to web front ends so users can look at it in real time. The web front end is a webapp that connects to a cluster of web servers (spray or play or whatever) via a websocket... and there can be many users interested in the same data.

Question: Since the front end user can connect to any web server in the cluster, how do I get the data back to the cluster in a way where it can be pushed to all the users interested in that particular datum? Do I get the datum to a single server and then somehow distribute it to all of the machines in the cluster? Is there a way for that single datum to go to all servers in the cluster and then each server decides whether there is a connected user that is interested in it and, if not, drops it?

Comment: How about a distributed pub/sub method? the backend servers subscribe to the distributed channel, the one that receives the datum from analytics then broadcast it on the channel, and the servers decide what to do with it.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Which service would you recommend using for pub/sub? Do Kinesis streams make sense here? Maybe Redis? Ideally I'd like to be able to subscribe to a subset of data instead of the entire firehose.

Comment: You may want to check out existing implementation for such use case. Cettia supports [tagging](http://cettia.io/projects/cettia-java-server/1.0.0-Alpha1/reference/#tagging) for handling a specific entity in the real world (many users interested in the specific data) and [clustering](http://cettia.io/projects/cettia-java-server/1.0.0-Alpha1/reference/#clustering). I'm the author of that project but you don't need to use it. Just look at the underlying concept and apply to your application. And I recommend Hazelcast as pub/sub because it is masterless and convenient.

Comment: Akka has its own pub/sub extension in the contrib library. Kinesis and Redis may be a bit overkill.

Comment: @Diego Martinoia If Kinesis is a choice for streaming geo-spatial data, then how to broadcast streamed data to mobiles ends?